# delay execution at every iteration of loops in php?

Tags: php

I have a for loop that echos div blocks at every iteration. I'm experimenting with PHP. The below code runs perfectly.

```
<div>
      <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++)
        {
          echo '<div class="blocks"></div>';
        }
      ?>
  </div>
```

I need to modify the loop in a way that it executes its statements at every **k** seconds so that I can see the code generating div blocks. I read PHP's documentation and tried the **sleep()** method but that doesn't seem to work. Adding that function makes the webpage load infinitely. How can I delay the execution of each iteration?

Comment: The response is generated before its sent to the clients browser,  on the server. You can't slowly generate a single page to be sent back. You'll need javascript if you want to slowly display the content. But you can't slowly generate it with php.  I think you're misunderstanding how server scripting languages work.

Answer (score 1):

If you used `sleep(n)`, your script will appear to wait `i * n` seconds and then just give you the whole list.

if you want to slowly show the list, you'll want to use javascript, not PHP.

Comment: Any particular reason why this feature isn't available on PHP? Just curious

Comment: Its not that this 'feature' is unavailable, this is how server-side languages work.